# I would like to make a list or map by list inside object using java streams

Tags: java, java-stream

Reading "Java 8 In Action" I created real life excercise to put object for example in message queue:

I have an Object that has a List inside. I would like to group a List of those objects with streams by elements from objects List.
I need Map or at least List, see example.

Example:

```
Beverage cola = new Beverage("Cola", Arrays.asList("cubes", "lemon"));
Beverage tea = new Beverage("Tea", Arrays.asList("sugar", "milk", "lemon"));


class Beverage{
    String name;
    List<String> adds;

    public Beverage(String name, List<String> adds) {
        this.name = name;
        this.adds = adds;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<String> getAdds() {
        return adds;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Beverage{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", adds=" + adds +
            '}';
    }
}
```

I have this:

```
final Map<List<String>, Beverage> collect = beveragesMenu.stream()
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Beverage::getAdds, beverage -> beverage));
```

and it produces:

```
Key: [cubes, lemon]: Beverage{name='Cola', adds=[cubes, lemon]}
Key: [sugar, milk, lemon]: Beverage{name='Tea', adds=[sugar, milk, lemon]}
```

but I need Map:

```
Key: [cubes]: Beverage{name='Cola', adds=[cubes, lemon]}
Key: [sugar,]: Beverage{name='Tea', adds=[sugar, milk, lemon]}
Key: [milk]: Beverage{name='Tea', adds=[sugar, milk, lemon]}
Key: [lemon]: Beverage{name='Tea', adds=[sugar, milk, lemon]},Beverage{name='Cola', adds=[cubes, lemon]}
```

or/and List:

```
Beverage{name='Cola', adds=[cubes]}
Beverage{name='Cola', adds=[lemon]}
Beverage{name='Tea', adds=[sugar]}
Beverage{name='Tea', adds=[milk]}
Beverage{name='Tea', adds=[lemon]}
```

Comment: You cann't hava duplicate keys in a map, i.e you cann't have `lemon` twice as key. You need a `Map<String, List<Beverage>>` instead of a `Map<String,Beverage>`

Comment: Yes, I made copy paste. I was thinking about grouping by Key and List of object. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that was my intention. Thank you for pointing out mistacke in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a list of beverages like:

```
List<Beverage> myBeverageList = List.of(new Beverage("Cola", Arrays.asList("cubes", "lemon")),
                                        new Beverage("Tea", Arrays.asList("sugar", "milk", "lemon"))
                                       );
```

you can generate a ingredients-to-list-of-beverage mapping:

```
Map<String, List<Beverage>> ingredientsToBeverageMapping = myBeverageList.stream()
    .flatMap(bev -> bev.getAdds().stream()
            .map(ingr -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(ingr, bev)))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
            Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 1):

For something, like this I suggest you go with a [flatMap](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stream-flatmap-java-examples/)

**Code:**

```
public List<Beverage> beverages = Arrays.asList(cola, tea);
beverages.stream()
         .flatMap(beverage -> beverage.getAdds().stream().map(add -> new Beverage(beverage.getName(), Collections.singletonList(add))))
         .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

*Output:*

```
[
    Beverage{name='Cola', adds=[cubes]}, 
    Beverage{name='Cola', adds=[lemon]}, 
    Beverage{name='Tea', adds=[sugar]}, 
    Beverage{name='Tea', adds=[milk]}, 
    Beverage{name='Tea', adds=[lemon]}
]
```

Comment: Looks great and can be passed as a List to some queue. 
Now I wonder about Map with List of those objects that can be processed futher in groups for processing.

Comment: I don't know how to mark two solutions but this one is also good.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. Basically for each "add", a map is created, then the each entry of the map is put to the list. You can create new `Beverage` objects from them as well.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Beverage cola = new Beverage("Cola", Arrays.asList("cubes", "lemon"));
        Beverage tea = new Beverage("Tea", Arrays.asList("sugar", "milk", "lemon"));

        Stream.of(cola, tea)
                .map(Main::mapBeverage)
                .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .forEach(System.out::println);

    }

    private static Map<String, Beverage> mapBeverage(Beverage beverage) {
        return beverage.getAdds()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        add -> add,
                        add -> beverage
                ));
    }
```

It outputs:

```
lemon=Beverage{name='Cola', adds=[cubes, lemon]}
cubes=Beverage{name='Cola', adds=[cubes, lemon]}
lemon=Beverage{name='Tea', adds=[sugar, milk, lemon]}
milk=Beverage{name='Tea', adds=[sugar, milk, lemon]}
sugar=Beverage{name='Tea', adds=[sugar, milk, lemon]}
```

Comment: Yes, looks great! Thank you!

Comment: How do you can have duplicate keys in the map?

Comment: @HadiJ It took me also a while to get it. He doesn't have a map but a stream of entries which he is printing out using foreach. So no worries about dups.

Comment: Yes, original question does not ask for a map but list.

Comment: My bad, I was thinking about Map and List.